# Creating an Object on button onClick event

Tags: javascript, html, object, button, onclick

im trying to create an object on an onClick event of a button. Don't know if its necessary but I declared the button in x.html and got the constructor of the object in y.js.
Hope you can help me.

Greetings, Max

Comment: share your codebase

Comment: Please may you edit the question and share a [mcve] of the issue?